# Problem to exclude object from array in storage - IONIC 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, storage

I am saving data in storage and everything is fine, but for deletion there is a confusion. Example: in the array I have 4 objects, when I click to delete the first one it always takes the last one and deletes, but if it is excluded from the last one onwards exclude normal.

CartService

http s : // pastebin .com/cTw3TWis

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please share the delete code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this code to delete the current record

write code in your ts file

```
fnDelete(data,i){
  this.yourArrayData.splice(i, 1); 
}
```

write code in html when you click on delete icon

```
<button ion-button (click)="fnDelete(data,$index)" color="danger">
                  <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
                  Delete
                </button>
```

Comment: @JoãoMello keep it happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
        var my_array = ["a","b","c","k","d"];
        var start_index = 3
        var number_of_elements_to_remove = 1;
        var removed_elements = my_array.splice(start_index, number_of_elements_to_remove);
        console.log(removed_elements);
        //["k"]
        console.log(my_array);
        //["a","b","c","d"];
```